# Use 5 elements in each loop run out of 100 elements

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am fetching data from google sheets.
and want to add commas to 5 elements at a time out of 102 elements.
I am unable to figure out this basic stuff too. My bad.
Also the loop fail when the total elements is not a multiple of 5.
how to get this done??

i tried this:

```
var SheetValues = currentSheet.getRange("A2:A"+lastRow).getValues();
length = SheetValues.length;
 for (var i=0; i <= length; i=5){
      ids = SheetValues.join(",");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many things wrong.

1. The loop condition should be `i < length`. Array indexes go from `0` to `length-1`.
2. `i=5` doesn't increment `i`, it just keeps setting it to `5`. That should be `i += 5;`
3. `SheetValues.join(",")` joins the entire array, not just the current group of `5`. Use `SheetValues.slice(i, i+5).join(",")` to get just the current group.
4. You need to do something with `ids` after assigning it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 5) {
    ids = SheetValues.slice(i, i+5).join(",");
    console.log(ids);
}
```

There's no problem when the length is not a multiple of `5`. If `i+5` is greater than the length, it will slice just to the end of the array. The last group will have fewer than `5` items in it.

The `for` loop stops whenever `i >= length`. It doesn't have to hit `length` exactly.

```js
const SheetValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
const length = SheetValues.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 5) {
    ids = SheetValues.slice(i, i+5).join(",");
    console.log(ids);
}
```

Comment: How will this work if the total is not the multiple of 5?

Comment: The last group will have less than 5 items in it.

Comment: Considering that the last group has only 3 items. In that case, will this loop work or fail?

Comment: Why do you think it would fail? `slice()` doesn't mind if `i+5` is past the end.

Comment: As per this code final group would be like.  1,2,3,, It will 2 commas if the group has only 3 values

Comment: No it won't. `slice()` simply stops at the last element, it doesn't add extra elements to the slice.

Comment: I've added a demo.

Comment: Okay, Awesome. Thanks